# void cannot be converted to boolean if statement error

Tags: java

```
private void btnSaveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        try 
        {
            DVD dvd = new DVD(txtTitle.getText(), 
                    Integer.parseInt(txtYear.getText()),
                    true);

            if(collection.addDVD(dvd))
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "dvd added successfully");
```

Basically i need to save my dvd collection when it closes down but the if statement gives me the error of void cannot be converted to boolean.

This is the addDvd method

```
public void addDVD(DVD inDVD) 
    {
        dvds.add(inDVD);
        inDVD.setID(nextID);
        nextID++;
    }
```

the void addDvd method can't be changed because it was given from my teacher...

Comment: When do you want to show a message? Is it required?

Comment: If method is `void` then it can't return a value.

Comment: This is why
To create a dvd we have to click on an add button when we add a child frame pops up and then it has the details that it needs to filled...and then needs to be saved when we click on save button

However we need to make sure that the year is numeric otherwise it will be an error, and if the same dvd already exists then we can't add it since it already exists?

Answer (score -1):

Why are you trying to test the return result of `addDVD()`?  You can just do:

```
collection.addDVD(dvd);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "dvd added successfully");
```

Comment: This is why
To create a dvd we have to click on an add button when we add a child frame pops up and then it has the details that it needs to filled...and then needs to be saved when we click on save button

However we need to make sure that the year is numeric otherwise it will be an error, and if the same dvd already exists then we can't add it since it already exists?

Comment: Well then you need to add those checks to `addDVD()` and have it return a `boolean`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
try {
// do all the work as above
// remove if statement 
collection.addDVD(dvd);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "dvd added successfully");
}
catch {
// catch the error here 
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "dvd not added successfully");
}
```

Comment: This is why
To create a dvd we have to click on an add button when we add a child frame pops up and then it has the details that it needs to filled...and then needs to be saved when we click on save button

However we need to make sure that the year is numeric otherwise it will be an error, and if the same dvd already exists then we can't add it since it already exists?

Comment: You can create a function that checks if the dvd already exist. E.g. you can use hashmap  <dvdTitle, dvdYear> when you add new dvd. Another function for checking if the dvd already added and make this function returns boolean